# Python comment-preserving parsing using only builtin libraries?

Tags: python, parsing, syntax, abstract-syntax-tree, concrete-syntax-tree

I wrote a library using just [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) and [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) libraries to parse and emit [uses [astor](https://github.com/berkerpeksag/astor) on Python < 3.9] internal Python constructs.

Just realised that I really need to preserve comments afterall. Preferably without resorting to a [RedBaron](https://github.com/PyCQA/redbaron) or [LibCST](https://github.com/Instagram/LibCST); as I just need to emit the unaltered commentary; is there a clean and concise **way of comment-preserving parsing/emitting Python source with just stdlib**?

Comment: `inspect.getsource()` returns the source code of an object including comments. Is this what you need?

Comment: No because I am modifying AST nodes, changing: docstrings; `ast.Assign`; `ast.AnnAssign`; and `ast.FunctionDef`/`ast.AsyncFunctionDef`. Inferring types, adding them as a type comment xor annotation; converting between docstring formats (incl. adding/remove types); and updating the `return` attribute of a function definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was writing a simple parser, without a meta-language in 339 source lines:
https://github.com/offscale/cdd-python/blob/master/cdd/cst_utils.py

##### Implementation of Concrete Syntax Tree [List!]

0. Reads source character by character;
1. Once end of statement† is detected, add statement-type into 1D list;

   - †end of line `if line.lstrip().startswith("#") or line not endswith('\\') and balanced_parens(line)` else continue munching until that condition is true… plus some edge-cases around multiline strings and the like;
2. Once finished there is a big (1D) list where each element is a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) with a `value` property.

#### Integration with builtin Abstract Syntax Tree [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html)

0. Limit `ast` nodes to modify—not remove—to: {[`ClassDef`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.ClassDef),[`AsyncFunctionDef`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.AsyncFunctionDef),[`FunctionDef`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.FunctionDef)} docstring (first body element [`Constant`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.Constant)|[`Str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.Str)), [`Assign`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.Assign) and `AnnAssign`;
1. [`cst_idx, cst_node = find_cst_at_ast(cst_list, _node)`](https://github.com/offscale/cdd-python/blob/f5559a4/cdd/doctrans_utils.py#L349);
2. if doc_str node then `maybe_replace_doc_str_in_function_or_class(_node, cst_idx, cst_list)`
3. …
4. Now the `cst_list` contains only changes to those aforementioned nodes, and only when that change is more than whitespace, and can be created into a string with `"".join(map(attrgetter("value"), cst_list))` for outputting to [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?#eval) or straight out to a source file (e.g., in-place overriding).

#### Quality control

0. 100% test coverage
1. 100% doc coverage
2. Support for last 6 versions of Python (including latest alpha)
3. CI/CD
4. (Apache-2.0 OR MIT) licensed

#### Limitations

0. Lack of meta-language, specifically lack of using [Python's provided](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) [grammar](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Grammar/python.gram) means new syntax elements won't automatically be supported (`match`/`case` is supported, but if there's new syntax introduced since, it isn't [yet?] supported… at least not automatically);
1. Not builtin to stdlib so stdlib could break compatibility;
2. Deleting nodes is [probably] not supported;
3. Nodes can be incorrectly identified if there are shadow variables or similar issues that linters should point out.

Answer (score -1):

Comments can be preserved by merging them back into the generated source code by capturing them with the tokenizer.

Given a toy program in a program variable, we can demonstrate how comments get lost in the AST:

```
import ast

program = """
# This comment lost
p1v = 4 + 4
p1l = ['a', # Implicit line joining comment for a lost
       'b'] # Ending comment for b lost
def p1f(x):
    "p1f docstring"
    # Comment in function p1f lost
    return x
print(p1f(p1l), p1f(p1v))
"""
tree = ast.parse(program)
print('== Full program code:')
print(ast.unparse(tree))
```

The output shows all comments gone:

```
== Full program code:
p1v = 4 + 4
p1l = ['a', 'b']

def p1f(x):
    """p1f docstring"""
    return x
print(p1f(p1l), p1f(p1v))
```

However, if we scan the comments with the tokenizer, we can
use this to merge the comments back in:

```
from io import StringIO
import tokenize

def scan_comments(source):
    """ Scan source code file for relevant comments
    """
    # Find token for comments
    for k,v in tokenize.tok_name.items():
        if v == 'COMMENT':
            comment = k
            break
    comtokens = []
    with StringIO(source) as f:
        tokens = tokenize.generate_tokens(f.readline)
        for token in tokens:
            if token.type != comment:
                continue
            comtokens += [token]
    return comtokens

comtokens = scan_comments(program)
print('== Comment after p1l[0]\n\t', comtokens[1])
```

Output (edited to split long line):

```
== Comment after p1l[0]
     TokenInfo(type=60 (COMMENT),
               string='# Implicit line joining comment for a lost',
               start=(4, 12), end=(4, 54),
               line="p1l = ['a', # Implicit line joining comment for a lost\n")
```

Using a slightly modified version of `ast.unparse()`, replacing
methods `maybe_newline()` and `traverse()` with modified versions,
you should be able to merge back in all comments at their
approximate locations, using the location info from the comment
scanner (start variable), combined with the location info from the
AST; most nodes have a `lineno` attribute.

Not exactly. See for example the list variable assignment. The
source code is split out over two lines, but `ast.unparse()`
generates only one line (see output in the second code segment).

Also, you need to ensure to update the location info in the AST
using `ast.increment_lineno()` after adding code.

It seems some more calls to
`maybe_newline()` might be needed in the library code (or its
replacement).

Comment: If the code is shuffled around by transforming the AST (e.g., two blocks of code are interchanged) , this scheme is unlikely to work because the merge step can't track the shuffling.

Comment: @IraBaxter: it could if the shuffle would also be recorded in the comment tokens list by updating the start and end line for each affected element.

Comment: Good luck capturing that.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for this solution. But there seems to be a lot of weird whitespace all over the place, not just in comments. Docstring especially are cumbersome… so what I ended up doing is writing an entirely new flat CST that retains all whitespace, and enables trivial unparsing. Whilst not requiring rewriting of all my `ast` only parser/emitters. See my answer for a detailed explanation + links.